# php in header url error

Tags: php, paypal

I have just a quick question. i was using a normal html link tag to redirect to a paypal checkout page and it was working fine even when i had php inside the url. but when i was using it in a php header
the url cuts off where i enter the php.

```
header('location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=XXXX&lc=UK&item_name=<? echo $product . " " . $server ?>&amount=<? echo $xprice1; ?>%2e00&currency_code=GBP&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest');
```

Comment: You should probably avoid bare spaces in the url (encode them instead) as the header may get cut because of them

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the PHP code inside of the location redirect as a string. The code is not being evaluated as PHP.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$url =  "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=XXXX&lc=UK&item_name=" . $product . " " . $server ."&amount=" . $xprice1 . "%2e00&currency_code=GBP&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest";
header('location: ' . $url);
```

Or, you could keep it in one line like so:

```
<?php
header('location: ' . "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=XXXX&lc=UK&item_name=" . $product . " " . $server ."&amount=" . $xprice1 . "%2e00&currency_code=GBP&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest");
```

Comment: I still get the same problem

Comment: Do the variables $product, $server, and $xprice1 all have values to them? I have tested this locally and it redirects to PayPal for me. You may also want to check that the headers are not being sent somewhere else. If the script sends anything to the browser before the header() call, then this will fail. Try placing this at the top of your code to see if it works. You may have better luck turning on error reporting and PHP warnings. It will tell you what line the headers were already sent from.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 header('location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=XXXX&lc=UK&item_name=<? echo $product' . " " . '$server ?>&amount=<? echo $xprice1; ?>%2e00&currency_code=GBP&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest');
```

This may solve your problem. Please dont forget to tick the answer right if it works.